# How do I add a css class to an Div element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I add a css class to an Div element in JQuery? I have a DIV with a css class and the div contains a form. After clicking on submit I want the original css class to disappear and a new class to be added? I'm using JQuery as a Framework

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the jQuery documentation? Should not have been hard to find that in there.

Comment: Much easier to ask and get the answer than spend time reading.

Comment: The jQuery documentation is very good, but it's sometimes a little hard to quickly find what you're after.

Comment: @activa, use http://api.jquery.com

Comment: hmm, a simple "jquery+add class" in google would give instant gratification

Comment: @redsquare: Hush! Don't mention Google! Some people think that Stack Overflow should re-create all the programming know-how in the world from scratch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#element_id").removeClass( "oldclass").addClass("newclass");
```

Answer (score 4):

To add a class, use addClass:

```
$('#myDiv').addClass("blah");
```

So upon your submit you can do something like:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').removeClass().addClass("blah");
});
```

Calling removeClass with no parameters removes all classes linked to that element. Alternatively, you can call removeAttr("style")

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
$("#target").addClass("newclass");
```

for adding the class to the elemet #target and

```
$("#target").removeClass("newclass");
```

to remove it.

If you dont know wether the class is already there or not you can use

```
$("#target").toggleClass("newclass");
```

if its there, it will be removed, and if its not there it will be added.

Answer (score -1):

Since OP didn't mention any ids I would go with a class selector and picking the first element in collection (which could be wrong, offcourse).

```
$(".OriginalClass").removeClass("OriginalClass").addClass("blah");
```

The original example was wrong, as the elements in the collection are regular objects and as such they don't have the removeClass and addClass methods.

The current example removes the class for all elements, which is still flawed, but in my opinion works better with what OP wanted.